# Gmail Event UI not syncing up?

Tags: icalendar

I used PHP to mail myself an email that has an attachment `invite.ics`.

The first few times I sent an email, I DID NOT get the following UI in gmail:

[image]

But then after a few more test sends, that UI started showing up for some reason.

I then changed the contents of my invite.ics so that the title changed from John Production Status to James Production Status.  WHen I sent myself another email,, gmail displayed the UI with the title John Production Status.  But when I downloaded invite.ics, it showed James Production Status.

Why does this happen?  And how do I get the UI to reflect the contents of `invite.ics`?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i fixed the issue in gmail.  Apparently in the contents of my invite.ics, I had to make sure that the field `UID` had a unique value for each deployment.  For some reason, that would force gmail to clear it's "cache".

Answer (score 0):

By changing the UID, you are not clearing any cache but rather are creating a brand new, unrelated event. If gmail is not taking into account new invitations, you may want to increase the SEQUENCE property to indicate that this is a new version of the same event.